# Which rsa library recommended for "react native" platform?

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native

Which rsa library recommended for "react native" platform with android support?

Thank you

**EDIT:**

I tried `react-native-rsa`:

```
var encrypted = '';
try {
  var RSAKey = require('react-native-rsa');
  const bits = 1024;
  const exponent = '10001';
  var rsa = new RSAKey();
  rsa.generate(bits, exponent);
  var publicKey = rsa.getPublicString(); 
  var privateKey = rsa.getPrivateString(); 
} catch (error) {
  console.log(1);
  console.log(error);
}

try {

  rsa = new RSAKey();
  rsa.setPrivateString(privateKey);
  var originText = 'Test 123 Test 321';
  encrypted = rsa.encrypt(originText);

} catch (error) {
  console.log(2);
  console.log(error);
}

try {
  rsa = new RSAKey();
  rsa.setPublicString(publicKey);
  var decrypted = rsa.decrypt(encrypted);
  console.log(decrypted);

} catch (error) {
  console.log(3);
  console.log(error);
}
```

But I got this error:

```
I/ReactNativeJS( 9238): 3                                                                                                                                                                                  
I/ReactNativeJS( 9238): { [TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'e.bitLength')]                                                                                                                    
I/ReactNativeJS( 9238):   line: 96781,                                                                                                                                                                     
I/ReactNativeJS( 9238):   column: 8,                                                                                                                                                                       
I/ReactNativeJS( 9238):   sourceURL: 'http://10.0.3.2:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false' }
```

Comment: Can you provide in which line is occurring the error?

Comment: The error occure in this line: var decrypted = rsa.decrypt(encrypted);

Comment: Check out `encrypted` var before this function call. It appears to be null.

Comment: I checked it. `encryped != null`

Comment: Please note that I am trying to **encrypt with privateKey** and **decrypt with publicKey**.

Comment: I will test the code and see if I get the same error.

Answer (score 5):

Try `react-native-rsa`, it's simple to use and will support android platform.

First install library using Npm:

`npm install react-native-rsa`

Generate RSA keys:

```
var RSAKey = require('react-native-rsa');
const bits = 1024;
const exponent = '10001'; // must be a string
var rsa = new RSAKey();
var r = rsa.generate(bits, exponent);
var publicKey = rsa.RSAGetPublicString(); // return json encoded string
var privateKey = rsa.RSAGetPrivateString(); // return json encoded string
```

Encript:

```
var rsa = new RSAKey();
rsa.setPublicString(publicKey);
var originText = 'sample String Value';
var encrypted = rsa.encrypt(originText);
```

Decript:

```
rsa.setPrivateString(privateKey);
var decrypted = rsa.decrypt(encrypted); // decrypted == originText
```

Reference: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-rsa

Comment: it doesn't work in case I'd have to use already generated public key I receive from API

Answer (score 0):

Use this package as it is update: [react-native-rsa-native](https://github.com/amitaymolko/react-native-rsa-native)

Answer (score 0):

Try this https://github.com/jerson/rsa-mobile
Native code used in react-native-fast-rsa and flutter-rsa

Comment: Please add more details supporting your answer.