# React native RSA encryption with a public PEM or SSLeay key

Tags: npm, react-native, rsa, pem, jwk

I am trying to find a working javascript library for react-native that will allow RSA public key encryption in PEM format.

I am not an expert in encryption and just starting out with react-native so please excuse me if i happened to miss something obvious.

So far i have tryed
[react-native-rsa](https://github.com/z-hao-wang/react-native-rsa) as recomended by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39878901/which-rsa-library-recommended-for-react-native-platform)
and
[react-native-rsa-util](https://github.com/lokielse/react-native-rsa-util).

I couldn't get react-native-rsa-util to work and react-native-rsa doesn't seem to accept public PEM keys but only keys in the JWK format.

The only reason i am not willing to use the JWK format is that i cannot find a PHP library that will decrypt the incoming message with a JWK key.

I would highly appreciate any help / pointers.

Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

I wrote [a PHP library](https://github.com/Spomky-Labs/Jose) that supports JWT encryption/decryption with a lot of other useful features including compression.

All algorithms referenced in the [RFC7518](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7518) and JWK/JWKSet are supported.

What you can do is convert your PEM key into JWK with my library:

```
<?php
use Jose\Factory\JWKFactory;

$jwk = JWKFactory::createFromKeyFile('/path/to/my/key.pem');

var_dump($jwk->getAll());
```

And to decrypt a JWT with your JWK and my library:

```
use Jose\Loader;

$input = 'eyJhbGciOiJS...';
$loader = new Loader();
$jwe = $loader->loadAndDecryptUsingKey($input, $jwk, ['RSA-OAEP-256'], ['A256CBC-HS512']); // The list of accepted key and content encryption algorithms depends on your needs
```

The variable `$jwe` is now [JWE Object](https://github.com/Spomky-Labs/jose/blob/master/src/Object/JWEInterface.php).
You can get the payload by calling `$jwe->getPayload();`

Do not hesitate to contact me on [the dedicated Gitter channel](https://gitter.im/Spomky-Labs/jose?utm_source=badge&utm_medium=badge&utm_campaign=pr-badge&utm_content=badge) if needed.

Comment: Thanks alot for you answer and your work with this awesome library!
It worked exactly as expected.